# SSIS 2017 Unexpected Termination when running 64-bit

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS solution with about 150 packages.  Two of the packages consistently fail with an "Unexpected Termination" error when running in 64-bit. They succeed when running in 32-bit runtime.

The packages that fail writes some rows to the destination before failing.

The source and destination for all data flows is the local SQL Server databases. I use SQL Server Native 11 OLE DB drivers.

Both packages contain DT_NTEXT data types, but so do some of the other packages that succeed.

The are nothing in the ErrirDumps folder (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Shared\ErrorDumps).  Also nothing in the Windows event log.

Below is an image of the dataflow task.  The LKP component only caches 5 rows.

[image: Data Flow Task]

Any help or ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: If the source and destination is the same, I suggest you don't use SSIS at all. Just run a query within the database

Comment: Were you able to check the error under SQL SERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO -> OBJECT EXPLORER -> Integration Services Catalogs ->"Your SSIS Database" -> "Particular package Deployed Folder" -> Project -> "Project Name" -> Packages -> "Package name" -> Right click reports ->Standard reports -> All execution

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with my SSIS package. After upgrading from 2010 32-bit to 2016 64-bit, the package stopped working. SQL Server Job doesn't show errors, and even verbose error logging does not provide useful information.

My packages were importing a few different spreadsheets in parallel. After changing the tasks to serial processing (import the next spreadsheets after the first one is done), the package works again.

Before updating your SSIS package, I suggest you disable tasks in your package and find out the source of the error. But hopefully this helps!

Comment: I faced slightly similar issue and your hint about 2010 and 2016 version of access runtime helped me to resolve the issue which I have now documented here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66985851/ssis-error-when-run-via-sql-job-while-connecting-to-ms-access-database-unexpect/67232944#67232944

Comment: Glad that it helps! :)
To this day, I still have 1 SSIS package that has this issue intermittently. For my situation, it generates an Excel file (using a blank template) and fails in the middle of writing. Rerunning the package a few times and the unexpected termination error will go away. So others might consider it if the package can be ran multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, or hopefully the same. The package could not be run using 64bit env and there were no logs either.

Just check your dotnet framework installation. There was a problem with file permissions at machine.config file within "Framework64" folder...